# In C#, how do I create an invalid X509Chain?

Tags: integration-testing, x509, x509certificate2

The **X509ChainStatusFlags** enum contains a lot of possible values: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chainstatusflags?view=netframework-4.8

Are there easy ways to construct a certificate and chain that produce some of these flags? I want to construct them in order to integration-test my certificate validation logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each different kind of failure requires a different amount of work to test for.  Some are easy, some require heroic effort.

The easiest: error code 1: `X509ChainStatusFlags.NotTimeValid`.

```
X509Certificate2 cert = ...;
X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationTime = cert.NotBefore.AddSeconds(-1);
bool valid = chain.Build();
// valid is false, and the 0 element will have NotTimeValid as one of the reasons.
```

Next up: `X509ChainStatusFlags.NotValidSignature`.

```
X509Certificate2 cert = ...;
byte[] certBytes = cert.RawData;
// flip all the bits in the last byte
certBytes[certBytes.Length - 1] ^= 0xFF;
X509Certificate2 badCert = new X509Certificate2(certBytes);
chain.ChainPolicy.ApplicationPolicy.Add(new Oid("0.0", null));
bool valid = chain.Build();
// valid is false. On macOS this results in PartialChain,
// on Windows and Linux it reports NotValidSignature in element 0
```

Next up: `X509ChainStatusFlags.NotValidForUsage`.

```
X509Certificate2 cert = ...;
X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
chain.ChainPolicy.ApplicationPolicy.Add(new Oid("0.0", null));
bool valid = chain.Build();
// valid is false if the certificate has an EKU extension,
// since it shouldn't contain the 0.0 OID.
// and the 0 element will report NotValidForUsage.
```

Some of the more complicated ones require building certificate chains incorrectly, such as making an child certificate have a NotBefore/NotAfter that isn't nestled within the CA's NotBefore/NotAfter.  Some of these heroic efforts are tested in https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4f9ae42d861fcb4be2fcd5d3d55d5f227d30e723/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/tests/DynamicChainTests.cs and/or https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4f9ae42d861fcb4be2fcd5d3d55d5f227d30e723/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/tests/RevocationTests/DynamicRevocationTests.cs.